# Is recurring payment gateway supported by payubiz?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payu

I am working on Zend framework 2 and need to add Payubiz payment gateway. but before going further, i need to clarify this question; Is recurring payment gateway supported by Payubiz or not?

If it is supported then how can i implement. Kindly provide some references.

Comment: Yes it may work... check this link... http://developers.payu.com/en/recurring.html
I already worked on subscription using payu so it will work for you

Comment: @FairyDancer Thanx for the good suggestion. Please let me know is payubiz and payu are same or different??

Comment: yes they are different with settlement and charges for the translation. In coding wise it both are same structure

Comment: I didn't get any option for recurring payment in payubiz. developers.payu.com/en/recurring.html  - this link is for payu only.